# Scikit-learn confusion matrix performing differently based on strings

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I have a really strange problem, I'm using sklearn confusion matrix `(from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix)` for my dataset, but I noticed that the values it was printing were very far off. I tried to debug it, and it seems to work with the first letters of the alphabet such as "a", "b", "c", "d" and numbers (0, 1, 2, 3).

However, if I use other letters ("g", "r", "m", "o") or words that are in the example on the website

> https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

I get really random results. Is this a known problem? The only solution I can think of right now is to get it printed correctly by using numbers and then fix the labels in Paint.. This is not a solution I really want for my thesis.

[image: "g", "r", "m" and "o" - wrong]

[image: "cat", "ant", "bird", "bear" - wrong]

[image: "a", "b", "c", "d" - correct]

As far as I can see this should all return the third result. Is there anything I'm missing or is there anyone that's had this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a `classes` argument to `plot_confusion_matrix` that doesn't match what `confusion_matrix` is using, leading those routines to use different mappings from classes to confusion matrix rows and columns. `confusion_matrix` uses one mapping, and `plot_confusion_matrix` uses another, causing the results to be scrambled.

You need a `labels` argument to `confusion_matrix` matching the `classes` argument to `plot_confusion_matrix`:

```
confusion_matrix(gr, rr, labels=mr)
```

Comment: This question is actually quite interesting, and this issue is related to the way confusion matrix handles label by default. It sorts them by lexicographical order, hence the difference in your results. The same behaviour happens in other part of sklearn, like in LabelEncoder. Now you know something more about sklearn :)